# How to list CheckBoxes in a vertical way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I create checkbox, I want them to be listed in a vertical way, and not horizontal. How am I be able to do this??

Html:

```
  <div id="cblist">
        <input type="checkbox" value="first checkbox" id="cb1" /> <label for="cb1">first checkbox</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSave" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following line:

```
$('<br/>').appendTo(container);
```

at the end of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Put checkboxs in `lable` and give the lable `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML, so you have lots of options. For example:

- Make a list element and put each checkbox in a `<li>`
- Append a `<br>` after each label

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<br>` tags or tables...

Make clean html like:

```
<div class="formGroup">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" />
  <label>your label</label>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" />
  <label>your label</label>
</div>
```

With css you can make formGroup display as Block-Elements ...

Good luck

Comment: User has asked for help on displaying checkboxes in vertical way, so reusing the existing code would be the simplest approach.
i.e. appending `<br/>` in existing javascript could be the easiest way to achieve what he desires.

Comment: Sure, but he appends new inputs into one existing div. In my opinion the better and cleaner way is to append grouped inputs and labels. So they are vertical and you have clean html ...

Answer (score -1):

Add the checkboxes using  a table, each checkbox in each row of a single column.